# Download ftp files over http using C#?

Tags: c#, http, ftp, filestream

I have a ftp server, where I have all the files stored. And it works fine with any ftp client. Now I have to download these file over HTTPS, I tried following approach but it is downloading the file in background and once download completes it asks for which location to save. It works fine if we have a small file, but when we have a large file, the browser keeps on loading till it download the file.

```
public ActionResult Download(string filePath)
{
    string fileName = "file.csv.gz";
    byte[] fileBytes = GetFile(@"\\myserver-ftp\f$\content\file.csv.gz");

    return File(
    fileBytes, "application/gzip", fileName);
}

 byte[] GetFile(string s)
{
    System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(s);
    byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
    int br = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    if (br != fs.Length)
        throw new System.IO.IOException(s);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I assume `GetFile` should be asynchronous. Then you can just `await`.

Comment: Can you help me to convert this method asynchronous, I am new to this.

Comment: Well, it really depends on how you're calling that method. Making a method `async` usually assumes the calling code also to be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download FluentFtp nuget package into your project.

Create a method like this:

```
public async Task<FtpStatus> DownloadFtpFile(string ftpPathOfFile)
{
    using (var client = new FtpClient(FtpHost))
    {
        client.Connect();
        return client.DownloadFile(localPathToDownload, ftpPathOfFile);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it asynchronously:

```
public ActionResult Download(string filePath)
    {
        string fileName = "file.csv.gz";
        var fileFullPath = @"\\myserver-ftp\f$\content\file.csv.gz";

        var ftpStatus = await DownloadFtpFile(fileFullPath);
    
        if(ftpStatus== FtpStatus.Success)
        {
           return File(GetFile(fileFullPath), "application/gzip", fileName);
        }
        else 
        {
           // return error message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in order to `await` something, the calling function (in your case `Download`)  should also be `async`. As it is your code won't compile.

Comment: I tried this code by making some changes, this code also waits for the complete file to download in local server keeping browser loading throughout the process. How can we download this  file in such a way as we download any software from website. It won't blocks the browsers tab.

Comment: Then you will return another thing except File. For example you will call await DownloadFtpFile and then you won't wait for response and return a View.